# Plink 1.9 equivalent of --score sum in Plink 2.0

Tags: plink

I have previously performing Allelic scoring in Plink 1.9 using:

```
plink \ 
--score sum sumstats.txt\
```

However, it seems this has changed in Plink 2.0. What is the equivalent function for Allelic scoring?

Answer (score 3):

```
plink2 --score cols=+scoresums
```

See https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/2.0/general_usage#colset and https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/2.0/score for details.

Comment: Hi a bit of explanation would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation for a comment but the place where the option to add scoresums is listed is here https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/2.0/formats#sscore